# Logstash Filter Plugin as a file

Tags: logstash, elk

I'm using `logstash 7.0` . I'm having multiple events to filter. Instead of having one single config file, I prefer to have multiple filter config files for each event.

As an example, I'm having a login event and I store that filter config in separate file. I wish to give file path in filter as below

```
filter {
  if [I]=="login_event" {
    file {
      path => "/home/logstash/config/login_event.txt"
    }
  } else if[I] == "other_event" {
    file {
      path => "/home/logstash/config/other_event.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

But I saw there is no file plugin available in filter. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want, one of them is running logstash using the [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) option with a pipeline pointing to a folder where you can save your filters in separated files.

For example, the following `pipelines.yml` would create a pipeline named `events` pointing to the config files stored in the folder `/etc/logstash/conf.d/events/`.

```
- pipeline.id: events
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/events/"
```

In the folder `/etc/logstash/conf.d/events/` you would need a file for your inputs, a file for your outputs and any filter files you need in the order that you want them to be processed in your pipeline.

For example, you would need something like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  91 Nov 30 00:30 00-input.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 155 Nov 30 00:34 01-filterA.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160 Nov 30 00:35 02-filterB.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  73 Nov 30 00:35 99-output.conf
```

The `00-input.conf` file would have your `input` block, the file `99-output.conf` would have your `output` block, and each `0X-filterN.conf` file would have a `filter` block.

For `login_event` would be something like this:

```
filter {
    if [I] == "login_event" {
        your filters
    }
}
```

And for `other_event` would be the same thing, just changing your conditional.

You will probably need a filter file before those two to parse your message and create the fields to use in your conditional, but the idea is the same, you just need to name your files in the order you want your filters to be executed.

You can also combine multiple pipelines and a message broker like `redis` or `kafka` to solve the same problem, in this case you would need a pipeline to receive your messages, parse them and store in a `list` or `topic` for each one of your different events, then you would have a different pipeline to consume from them.

Comment: Thats working fine. Can I create an output folder inside conf.d/events and place all output files separately??

Comment: Never tried having a sub-folder, but I think it should work, just try to keep the naming convention, name the folder `99-outputs` and the files something like `99-01-outputA.conf`, `99-02-outputB.conf` and goes on.